# AdGroupAdService, if one of them is rejected

Tags: google-ads-api

When creating 100 TextAds with the AdGroupAdService, if one of them is rejected because its headline is >25 characters, what happens to the batch?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the [`partialFailure`](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/headers#partialFailure) header. If it's set to `true`, then the operations which do not cause any error will be applied. If it's not set or `false`, then the whole batch will fail.

Also note that not all services support `partialFailure` (but `AdGroupAdService` does).